# Favicon and splash screen not displaying in Quasar

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen, favicon, quasar

When I run the app in Cordova mode, neither the splash screen nor the favicon appears.
Question is how can favicon and splash screen be displayed.

My run command:

`quasar dev -m cordova -T android`

I use
Quasar 1.17.2
Icongenie 2.4.2
Cordova 11.0.0
Node 12.22.9

Answer (score 2):

In my case there was something wrong in my config.xml (in src-cordova).

Try:

```
icongenie verify
```

If you get this error message:

> ERROR: platform not installed!

then add the platform name for android and ios in your config.xml (in src-cordova):

```
<platform name="android">
</platform>

<platform name="ios">
</platform>
```